# Cost of network connection check in Android?

Tags: android, networking

I have this code:

```
        NetworkInfo netInfo = m_NetworkManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean bConnected = (netInfo != null) && netInfo.isConnected()
```

I'm planning to use this before each network request.
Is this code time consumpting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be a problem. If its your design requirement then use it. However, if you really want to see the time consumed by this code then you may easily calculate it too.

Comment: Actually I'm affraid of calling too frequently system functions. Can this be a problem - a lot of memory alocs or instances of classes? I have multiple threads working with network.

Comment: I've run this code at a pace of 1 second in a continuous loop for about a minute and it didn't cause any Garbage Collection. So you are safe to continue with this approach :)